# How should I structure a larger program using python instead of just one big file with code?

Tags: python, structure, organization, code-organization, project-organization

Sorry if the title is confusing.

What I am trying to say is this:
I have worked with Python before, but I'm by no means an expert. So far everything I have done has just been 'somefile.py' with lots of methods and code in it, but it doesn't really have any organizational structure. In Java (which I am more familiar with than Python), there are usually different classes that each have methods and are called from each other. How do you make a file full of code organized and structured when working on a large project? Break them up into files by class?

Hopefully this is clearer. Let me know if this needs clarification.

Comment: You can break them up into files where the functions are related even if you don't use classes. It's called "decomposition".

Comment: In Python you can also create classes. So basically what you do can in Java you can do it in Python.

Comment: So you have 1 file with only methods, no classes?  Can you tell us what kinda program it is & how you use it?  For example, command line utilities and a Django app both have certain *natural* organization schemes, given their respective domains.  In the abstract, harder to answer.

Comment: @JLPeyret what i am currently working on is a command line utility that just runs in the background. I may at some point give it a GUI

Comment: if you are using a command line, then it makes sense to split concerns between a) the code that deals with command line parameters (look into argparse for that) and b) the code that does the actual work.  So you'd have an argparser class and a batch class with run method.  If you add a GUI, I suggest you keep that out of batch.py (example names) and instead have gui.py import batch, call argparser and then call batch.run().  So a command line utility is actually quite a good learn.  Also, make sure you understand what runs on import vs what runs as main - that's probably trickiest part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the file unit is called module. Modules are organized in packages.

You usually put your classes each in a module and also use modules to group related code that doesn't belong to any class. Related modules are grouped in packages (physically represented by directories) which effectively create namespaces.

Then you use the `import` command to import the desired pieces of the code into other modules.

You can read about modules, packages and import in the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html).

Logically, it isn't much different than Java or other languages.